# Hook before all functional tests run

Tags: grails

Is it possible to get a pre commit before all grails functional tests are run?  This would mean if you have 100 functional tests, this hook with be invoked once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the Bootstrap.

```
import grails.util.Environment

class BootStrap {  

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
            // test setup here
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
        // teardown here (if necessary)
    }
}
```

This will run once the application starts in Test mode, which is what you want